# Coldfusion VARIABLES scope fails where evaluate works

Tags: coldfusion, scope, eval

I've getting the following error when using the VARIABLES scope with a dynamic variable name:

```
Element wlc_period is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.VariableScope.
```

When I try to run this code:

```
<cfparam name="wlc_period#y#" default="36">

<cfscript>
wlc_period      = VARIABLES['wlc_period#y#'];
</cfscript>
```

But if I use `evaluate()`, it works:

```
<cfscript>
wlc_period      = evaluate('wlc_period#y#');
</cfscript>
```

At the time of execution, the **y** variable is an empty string, the code gets used elsewhere in a loop though, so this can sometimes be populated with an integer, 1 - 5.

The code should be trying to access **wlc_period**, which works if I just do a simple dump:

```
<cfparam name="wlc_period#y#" default="36">

<cfscript>
writedump(wlc_period);
</cfscript>
```

I'd rather use the VARIABLES scope instead of evaulate(), am I missing something here?

Comment: The variable your specifying in your error is not the same as the one in your code examples? is this mistaken or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep and I can add than running the following is working perfectly <cfset y = "">
<cfparam name="wlc_period#y#" default="36">

<cfscript>
wlc_period      = VARIABLES['wlc_period#y#'];
</cfscript>

Comment: I had a long list of variables, wlc_period, wlc_salary, wlc_mileage, I was getting the errors on each of them, I may have got a little mixed up during testing, I will double check and update the question

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as expected for me.

```
<cfset y = "">
<cfparam name="wlc_period#y#" default="36">

<cfscript>
   wlc_period      = VARIABLES['wlc_period#y#'];
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#wlc_period#">
```

If you have only that in a .cfm file, does that work for you?

I suspect that the issue you're experiencing is unrelated to the code that you posted.

Comment: That works fine... I will try commenting out everything else in the template and bringing things back line by line until I find the cause

Comment: If you're happy updating your question with more code, then someone might be able to spot the issue faster.

Comment: I can put the full template in (up to the point it crashes) and a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `VARIABLES` scope is. Or possibly what really scope variables are.

Scope variables are values stored in a specific set. For instance, the `FORM` scope stores all values passed from a FORM post. The `URL` scope stores all values passed in the query string of the URL.

The VARIABLES scope is for use in ColdFusion Components (CFCs). It is used to keep certain CFC properties reusable, but private. The VARIABLES scope is not simply an object that stores all variables.

Looking at your code, `wlc_period#y` is simply a local variable that you're setting. I would suggest storing the value in a Local scope. I like to use "LOCAL" for local variables:

```
<cfparam name="LOCAL.wlc_period#y#" default="36">

<cfscript>
wlc_period      = LOCAL['wlc_period#y#'];
</cfscript>
```

You probably should scope `y` as well.

When you scope variables properly like this, you avoid running into problems where multiple scopes have the same variables.

Comment: Your answer implies there is no VARIABLES on CFM pages being executed and it is only for CFCs or perhaps the original question should note this is in a CFC.  I just think that should be clarified because doing something like this on a Test.cfm page: <cfset y  = 1 /> <cfparam name="wlc_period#y#" default="36">  <cfscript> wlc_period = VARIABLES['wlc_period#y#']; </cfscript> <cfdump var="#VARIABLES#" /> will in fact show that we end up with a Variables.wlc_period, variables.y, and variables.wlc_period1

Comment: As @Snipe656 said, any variable I declare on a CFM page should appear in the VARIABLES scope. I was under the impression the VARIABLES scope was like a GLOBAL scope for the page at runtime, which is why simple declarations like <cfset y = 1> will appears as VARIABLES.y = 1. I am aware of how scopes work, eg FORM, URL, APPLICATION etc, but I am having trouble understanding the VARIABLES scope present in CFM pages at the moment